# XSD: disallow empty element

Tags: xsd, element

I have an XML Schema that looks like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="A" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="B" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="C" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="32"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The following is valid according to this schema:

```
<root xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="MySchema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
</root>
```

However, I'd like to make the above XML invalid.

More specifically, I'd like to require:
  1.  that the `<root>` have at least one child element, be it an `<A>`, a `<B>`, or a `<C>`, and
  2.  that the `<root>` have at most one `<A>` child, and at most one `<B>` child.

Suggestions?

---

Solution is:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="A"/>
                    <xs:element name="B" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element name="C" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="32"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="B"/>
                    <xs:element name="C" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="32"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="C" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="32"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using exactly one xs:choice of A, B, or C followed by 0 or more of each of them?

Ah, with your edit it would have to be something like a choice of A, AB, or B followed by 0 to 32 Cs. Yes?

Comment: Your suggestions led me to the answer, Kate.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `minOccurrs=1` to the `xs:sequence`?